# Function is not being executed within setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use following code with React Native:

```
...

_getContentHeight() {
    if (this.refs.AccordionContent) {
        this.refs.AccordionContent.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
            // Sets content height in state
            this.setState({
                height: this.props.expanded ? height : 0,
                content_height: height
            });
        });
    }
},

componentDidMount() {
    // Gets content height when component mounts
    // without setTimeout, measure returns 0 for every value.
    // See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/953
    setTimeout(this._getContentHeight);
    // tried setTimeout(this._getContentHeight.bind(this); 
},

...
```

Now, when I debug the app in chrome, I see, that I never get to the `_getContentHeight()`. Now I am pretty sure that it has to do something with asynchronous calls etc. But is there a way to debug this, and see what values I get for height and `content_height`?

Help is needed, especially in understanding setTimeout/asynchronous function calls.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? I see two things worth investigating: check that `this` is bound to what you think it is. Secondly, your call to `setTimeout` is missing the 2nd parameter; if you want the async call to happen as soon as possible put a value of `10` or lower as that is the least amount of time a browser will wait to run events in the queue (I think a value of `0` can give problems).

Comment: @Halcyon That parameter is optional, surprisingly

Comment: Are you sure that `componentDidMount()` is called? @halcyon the second parameter isn't necessary if you want that the function is called as soon as possible, but asynchronous.

Comment: are you sure `_getContentHeight` isn't called? It looks like it's probably called but your `this` reference isn't what you think it is, so you never enter the if block

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach: componentDidMount() is called. I printed console.log in this method which confirms this. I just never get into the _getContentHeight.

Comment: `setTimeout` runs in a window context that is `this` means `window`. You can rewrite your call as  
`var that=this;  
setTimeout(function(){that._getContentHeight();},0);`

Comment: @andyk When debugging in chrome i can confirm that this is the correct this. (unfortunately :P)

Comment: @AlexanderKudryashev Unfortunately it gives me same result....

Comment: @bigpun86 did you tried my posted answer?

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach i tried but doesn´t work either. This is really weird....

Comment: 1. `setTimeout` requires 2 arguments: _function object_ and _timeout_ in milliseconds.
2. Function called from `setTimeout` runs in `window` content (`this == window`)
3. To make sure it is so set breakpoint at `this._get...`
4. Before `setTimeout` call `this` is you object. assign it to `that` and use inside  the function.

Comment: Also make sure that `this._get...` works fine without `setTimeout`

Comment: We´ll the function will be called without using setTimeout, but as mentioned, i need to call it asynchronously to receive correct values from measure function....

Comment: `this` is used inside `_getContentHeight` as well. Call from `setTimeout` (`window` context) make it useless. Set `var that = this;` outside the functions but inside your component and use `that` everywhere instead of `this`.

Comment: See update: https://jsfiddle.net/AlexKudryashev/nv0y01z7/3/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest moving the call to `measure` inside `componentDidMount` to make sure your functionality works before abstracting it and dealing with any scoping or object reference issues that you might be facing now.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.AccordionContent.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
      // Sets content height in state
      this.setState({
        height: this.props.expanded ? height : 0,
        content_height: height
      });
    });
}
```

Update:

I've wrapped your code in a react class and got the measure object to error out @ https://jsfiddle.net/x7w62w99/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  _getContentHeight() {
            console.log(this.refs)
      if (this.refs.AccordionContent) {
          this.refs.AccordionContent.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
              // Sets content height in state
              this.setState({
                  height: this.props.expanded ? height : 0,
                  content_height: height
              });
          });
      }
  },
  componentDidMount() {
      setTimeout(this._getContentHeight);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div ref='AccordionContent'>
        Hello {this.props.name}
      <div id='AccordionContent'>
      some stuff
      </div>
    </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: I tried this before. But unfortunately i get 0 for every value inside of measure. According to this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/953, the fix is using setTimeout.

Comment: I put some of your code in a jsfiddle example and got the measure function to error out. https://jsfiddle.net/x7w62w99/ Beyond this, I think I'd need more of the wrapping react object to debug it further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function(){
     this._getContentHeight.bind(this)
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Use This:

```
setTimeout({
   this._getContentHeight
}, the delay you want);
```

SetTimeout takes two parameteres.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: "SetTimeout takes two parameteres" — It does, but the first one cannot be a plain object, and **the second one is optional**.